# Ubuntu audio recording seems to pickup playback via another application

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, microphone, audio-recording

New to audio recording on Linux, and I have 2 audio interfaces on my PC. An onboard intel HDA (Realtek ALC887 codec) interface, to which a relatively inexpensive (but still surprisingly decent for home-recording) mic called BM-800 is attached (to mic port, on front-panel of the PC). The other audio interface is a USB2.0 based Behringer UMC-22 (TI Burr-Brown based), which while connected to PC via USB, doesn't have any inputs or output connected. Also, I have a tiny desktop stereo speaker (as an el-cheapo monitor) connected to onboard intel HDA's via headphone out jack of rear panel of PC, and a headphone connected to headphone out jack of front panel of PC.

I have used alsamixer to turn down (to zero) the output of the tiny desktop stereo speakers and I can play an audio backing track in VLC, to confirm that the audio is heard only on the headphones connected to the front-panel of onboard audio, and no sound is being produced from the tiny desktop speakers.

In this situation I am using Audacity to record the audio captured by the BM-800 microphone, connected to mic-in of the front panel (onboard audio soundcard), while playing the backing track using VLC on my headphone. There is about 1.5feet distance most of the time, between the headphone (which is a closed back, and has extremely limited sound leakage), and the BM-800 mic (which is a large-diaphragm condensor mic). I can see the audio capture waveform, but when I playback, I notice that the backing track is fully present (as in overdub) on the Audacity recording, that was meant to only capture my voice via BM-800.

I am at loss, as to how is the output of VLC captured by Audacity ? There appears to be some sort of internal application routing of audio from VLC to Audacity. I have already double-checked QJackCtl to see if there is any Jack patching done, but there is none.